# extracting only numeric data from character and numeric data

Tags: r, timestamp, character, numeric

I want to pull hours out of timestamp from start to current time.

example below:

```
 x<-Sys.time();
 x;
 #[1] "2013-11-05 15:39:38 CST"
 y<-Sys.time();
 y;
 #[1] "2013-11-05 16:06:06 CST"
 y-x;
 #Time difference of 26.46707 mins
```

What I want is the time difference between y and x and only the numeric part
     # 26.46707

I have multiple time-stamps in my data that I will subtract from start point to get hours of blah., What I want to do after this is build a data-frame with the hours data to make a variation plot. Any ideas would be great on how to get the 26.46707 isolated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: uh.... `as.numeric(y-x)`? Use `difftime` to specify units.

Comment: Thanks Senor O, didn't think of that simple function.

Comment: No problem. I'd recommending checking out how classes in `R` work if something like this comes up again (note what happens with `class(y-x)` and `unclass(y-x)`)